# How do you give a wagtail/django Page a custom url to serve at?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

In `wagtail/django` how do you make a basic `wagtail Page model`, create the html template, and then tell that model to serve as a view for a specific url?

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page

class MyPage(Page):
  title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
  #...
```

I want the url to register like

```
url(r'^monkey/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9]+)$', ...)
```

But I don't have a common `urls.py` folder its stored outside of the project. I tried using the `RoutablePageMixin`, but I believe that serves for subpages. I also know where to store the html template within the structure so that is not a problem.

Comment: Please can you give more details on why you don't have an accessible urls.py? That's a standard part of any Django project, and you're going to be a bit stuck if you can't edit it.

Answer (score 2):

You might want something like:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.views import View
from wagtail.core.views import serve

class WagtailPageServeView(View):
    """
    A default way to serve up wagtail pages in urls
    """

    wagtail_slug = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.wagtail_slug:
            return serve(request, self.wagtail_slug)
        else:
            raise Http404(
                f"WagtailPageServeView missing 'wagtail_slug'. Cannot serve "
                f"request.path: {request.path}"
            )
```

Then you can do something like this in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^$', WagtailPageServeView.as_view(wagtail_slug='/'), name='home'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Wagtail, you are creating a page type and then creating instances of the page type in the CMS.

Even if you are only going to use this page once, you still need to make a type. Following this logic, page urls are defined inside the CMS through the page's parent and [slug](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/editor_manual/new_pages/the_promote_tab.html?highlight=slug). Most likely, you could achieve what you want through these means.

If you want to override your page template and create a custom url, you can override the [get_url_parts method](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/topics/pages.html#customising-url-patterns-for-a-page-model) on your model.

Also, if you want to skip Wagtail for this page specifically, remember that Wagtail is just built over Django. You can always create a new module and define the url in that model. If you check your site `urls.py`, you will see the wagtail url patterns. You can change it to look something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other urls...
    url(r'wagtail/', include(wagtail_urls)),
    url(r'^monkey/', ('monkey_app.urls', 'monkey_app')),
]
```